# Continuously train CoreML model after deploy on Server?

Tags: machine-learning, python

I am working on face recognition with CoreML.I make a CoreML model with python Turi Create and put it on Server. User download it and compile on device but there is one problem if we want to do any updation like add a new user's face then we have to make this model again and then put it on Server.I want that if i deploy a model on Server then for every new user i train this model on the server.Is there any possible ways to do this.